# React with Node not working in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I've seen tons of tutorials on setting up React/Node/mySql to work in development, which I've done and it works perfectly.

But, now that I need to put the production build on a VPS server, it's not working and I can't figure why.   I have verified that my node backend does connect to and query the database.

The problem is, my React front end doesn't seem to find the node backend. What configuration am I missing that it can't find it? When I click the button that should query the backend and display results, it just returns HTML of the page not found page.  I'm at a loss to what configuration I have missed.

Comment: What technologies are you using to deploy your project? Have you checked if their addresses are pointing to the right place? What about environment variables?

Comment: I guess that's my confusion, I haven't seen anywhere how to configure all that. I ran the npm build to build the react site, and it displayed as expected on my production server.  Then i installed node with dependencies and run that through a terminal window, and it connects.  It's just that the front end doesn't seem to be able to hit the routes.